# How do you link a C++ library from the command line

Tags: c++, command-line, compilation, linker

I am making C++ library that has multiple headers (all headers having a .h, .cpp, and .o file), how do I make the library linkable so that the user can compile it like: `g++ main.cpp -o binaries -l libraryName`?

Comment: The best way I found to do this is to spend a few months learning the GNU toolchain: how to use autoconf, automake, and libtool. It's libtool that will take care of this functionality, but in order to use it effectively you also need autoconf and automake. You can always run `ld` with the appropriate options and build the shared library yourself, but there are a bunch of other details that libtool takes care of you, that will trip you up until you get it right. Learn how to use libtool. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I make the library linkable

Like so:

```
ar ruv libraryName.a foo.o bar.o baz.o
```

This is best achieved by writing a `Makefile`, which will automate the build process for you. Something like this:

```
all: libraryName.a
clean:
        rm -f *.o  # important: use TAB, not spaces for indentation here.

SRCS = foo.cpp bar.cpp baz.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

libraryName.a: ${OBJS}
```

P.S. To use `libraryName.a`, do this:

```
g++ -o exename main.cpp -lbraryName
```

and not this (requires library named `liblibraryName`):

```
g++ -o exename main.cpp -l libraryName
```

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian. what does the 'u' in "ruv" mean? because when I try it says: ```'u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')```